# How to split and save lines from a CSV file in C#

Tags: c#, string, file, csv, split

I do have the following CSV file:

34416;15,14;22,67;71,51;73,59;73,1;67,19;64,07;64,29;67,94; ...

...

Now, I would like to save the first number 34416 and replace every semicolon with it, but do not replace the first semicolon.

Now, there is the next line. Same procedure, just another number at the beginning.

```
public List<string> ConvertFile()
    {
        string allLines = string.Empty;
        allLines = GetLinesFromFile();

        for (int i = 0; i < GetLinesFromFile().Length; i++)
        {
            string[] split = allLines.Split(new Char[] { ';' });
            string number = split[i];
            allLines.Replace(";", ";34416|");
        }

        List<string> re = new List<string>();
        re.Add(allLines);

        return re;
    }
```

I am very new to C# coding - could you please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know that a CSV data cell can also contain semicolons? Take a look at RFC-4180: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt (point 2.6)

Comment: You're calling the `.Replace(..)` on the `allLines` whereas you should be calling it on the current line like, `allLines.Replace(";", ";34416|");`. And replace the 34416 with the first number of every line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rethink your logic. First of all `GetLinesFromFile()` seems to return a string; I'd have that return a `List<string>` instead (with each line from the file being one string). And then you can do this:

```
public List<string> ConvertFile()
{
    var result = new List<string>();

    foreach(var line in GetLinesFromFile())
    {
        var lineParts = line.Split(';');
        var fixedLine = line.Replace(";", ";" + lineParts[0] + "|");
        result.Add(fixedLine);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Okay, so `lines` has to be a `List<string>`?

Comment: Oops, forgot to add the function; edited my code to fix it: replaced `lines` with the call to `GetLinesFromFile()`.

Comment: CHAR does not contain a definition for SPLIT / REPLACE.

Comment: Like I said: change `GetLinesFromFile()` so it returns a `List<string>` or a `string[]` with each line from the file being one string. Use [ReadAllLines()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezwyzy7b.aspx) for instance.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public List<string> ConvertFile( )
        {
            string allLines = GetLinesFromFile();
            List<string> re = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < allLines.Length; i++)
            {
                string[] split = allLines.Split(new Char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                allLines.Replace(";", ";" + split[0] + "|");
                re.Add(allLines);
            }
            return re;
        }
```

Comment: if this code working fine for you mark as correct and vote it.